# Can I implicitly create member variables via attributes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I would like to create an C# attribute that accepts a Type parameter.

```
[MyAttribute(typeof(FooBar))]
public class MyClass
    {
```

Adding this attribute to a class should, among other things, tell Visual Studio implicitly that this class has a member variable of that type, with a name derived from the type.

For example, adding the attribute with the parameter `typeof(FooBar)` should implicitly create the member variable `private FooBar _foobar;`.

I would like to be able to access that member via autocomplection in the IDE, so doing this at runtime would be too late.

Is this possible at all? How could I achieve this?

Comment: Not directly. Why do you need this?

Comment: To give you better answers, you should describe the problem you're facing where that attribute that would hypothetically add that field would be the solution. It would possibly give us hints that would allow us to help you with the original problem, and not with your current solution. Wouldn't either class inheritance or interfaces help you with requirements like this?

Comment: @CodeCaster I was simply looking for a convenient way of avoiding boiler plate code. I want to retrieve a dependency from a central source by type and store it in a member variable. But I was hoping I could avoid having to explicitly define the member variable and include the code for retrieving the dependency each time. Instead, I wanted to define an attribute that would tell the IDE before compilation that a member variable of a certain type and name is present, and retrieve the dependencies at runtime depending on the present attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without something that rewrites the IL after the compiler has done its thing.

Except for a short list of attributes built into .NET and specifically handled by the compiler, attributes doesn't impact code at all, they're just metadata stored in the final assembly.

One way would be to use something like [Postsharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) which does the very thing I describe above.

Basically, Postsharp and similar systems takes the final assembly produced by the .NET compiler apart, reads the metadata (attributes and other things) then rebuilds the assembly from the ground up, injecting more code depending on those attributes.

However, with stock .NET and C#, no, this is not possible.

---

As [@MarcinJuraszek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1163867/marcinjuraszek) comments, this may be possible with Roslyn, the new compiler platform that Microsoft is going to launch. I have little experience with this so my answer is related to current stable releases, which includes .NET 4.5 and C# 5.0.

Comment: It might be possible with Roslyn rewriters.